# Initial value problem with two equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given the IVP below:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{y}{y+x}+\ln(x+y)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{y}{y+x},$$

$$y(0)=e, x(0)=0$$

I started by dividing the two equation to get rid of the $dt$. I got:

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=-1+\frac{\ln(x+y)(x+y)}{-y}$$

I tried to substitute with $u=x+y$ but it din't help

Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding the 2 equations and substituting $u=x+y$ gives $\frac{du}{dt} = \ln u$ which is separable, but the integral isn't elementary

Answer (score 1):

Sum the equations to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x+y)=\ln(x+y),\quad x+y\bigr|_{t=0}=e.
$$
Solve it to get $x+y$, and then use the second equation to get $y$. The integrals coming up cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.